# camera has stopped unexpectedly

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread

I have a Micromax A25 running Android version 2.3.6. The camera no longer works on it. When I open up the camera app, it closes with an error message saying `.com.mediaket.camera has stopped unexpectedly`.

What should I do?

Comment: Can you access the gallery app? Did you install any apps that restrict the use of the camera? Are you rooted? Do you remember what things or steps you did, prior to the camera app FC'ing?

Answer (score 1):

### Clear App Cache/Data

The first thing you should try is clearing the cache for your camera app. In the phone settings, go to the applications manager and locate your camera app (the same screen you would use to uninstall the app). If your camera app is built-in, you may have to navigate to a tab that shows *all* apps installed, not just ones installed by the user.

There should be a button called <kbd>Clear cache</kbd>. Click this and then try opening the camera app.

If it still crashes, go back to the same screen and click <kbd>Clear data</kbd>. This will *not* delete your photos; it will reset the camera app settings and return it to the initial state when it was first installed.

### Use a different camera app

Try installing another camera app from the Play Market. There are plenty of free ones available. If those work, perhaps your camera app is simply buggy or doesn't work with your device.

If other apps still can't access the camera, you may have a deeper problem.

### Factory Reset

As a last resort, you can reset your device to factory settings. Make sure you back up any important data to your computer or to an external SD card.

### Re-flash Rom

If a factory reset doesn't do it, you'll have to delve into deeper waters. Look around on XDA Forums or other places on how to flash a Rom to your device.

### Replace Hardware

There is always the slight chance that your hardware is physically damaged. In that case, you'll just need to replace it or live without a camera.

Answer (score 0):

There are two fixes main to this problem that I know of.

1) The first is restarting the device.

2) The second is factory reset. (If you choose this you may want to make sure you backup anything important.)

Other fix:
Clear your device cache. (Sometimes this works, doing it differs from device to device.)